# htaccess force ssl for all ip's except 127.0.0.1

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently using the following to force https for every one. I would like to disable this for ONLY 127.0.0.1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an additional condition to very the IP like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```